# What is the purpose of lex and yacc?

Tags: compile, c

I'm currently trying to develop a compiler of my own using the C language. I came across this thread that says that learning lex and yacc will help in building compilers. However, I don't understand its purpose and why it's needed in order for me to build my own compiler. I apologize for my lack of understanding in creating compilers, but I thought that using C and learning compiler concepts and theories is already enough to build it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you haven't been able to find this answer yourself, then you may want to start with something less advanced than parsing and compiling C. It's great that you want to learn, but this may be much more of a task than you imagine - I'd suggest starting with something smaller in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Information is easy to find.

For example, from
[The Lex & Yacc Page](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/):

> A compiler or interptreter for a programminning language is often
> decomposed into two parts:
>
> 1. Read the source program and discover its structure.
> 2. Process this structure, e.g. to generate the target program.
>
> Lex and Yacc can generate program fragments that solve the first task.
>
> The task of discovering the source structure again is decomposed into
> subtasks:
>
> 1. Split the source file into tokens (Lex).
> 2. Find the hierarchical structure of the program (Yacc).

Read this page and study the examples.

There is also nothing wrong with using C and learning
compiler concepts and theories.
Lex & Yacc can only complement this knowledge.